# Can an algorithmic process ever give true random numbers?

Tags: random, theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [True random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702/true-random-number-generator)

I have worked with random functions in python,ruby, MATLAB, Bash and Java. Nearly every programming language has a function to generate random numbers. However, these apparently random sequences are termed as pseudo-random number sequences as the generation follows a deterministic approach, and the sequence seems to repeat (usually with a very large period).

My question, can an algorithmic/programming process ever yield true random numbers ? The questions probably is more of theoretical computer science than just programming !

Comment: @cletus: The usual definition is “not based on any algorithmic process” which kinda makes this question self-answering ;-)

Comment: @cletus : See this, http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Comment: [Here's the Dilbert answer](http://www.dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/300/2318/2318.strip.gif) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to generate a true random number without relying on hardware. See [True random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702/true-random-number-generator)

Comment: @James Westgate: Yeah, you are right ! May be not a duplication, but they are very similar. I will do a roll-back ASAP