# Adding additional ones that surround other values of one in a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Given a vector of zeros and ones in MATLAB, where the zeros represent an event in time, I would like to add additional ones before and after the existing ones in order to capture additional variation.

**Example:** I would like to turn `[0;0;1;0;0]` into `[0;1*;1;1*;0]` where `1*` are newly added ones.

Comment: Did any of the solutions presented here work for you? Also, do consider accepting solutions, as you haven't done that for your recently posted questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `A` to be the input column vector -

```
%// Find all neighbouring indices with a window of [-1 1] 
%// around the positions/indices of the existing ones
neigh_idx = bsxfun(@plus,find(A),[-1 1])

%// Select the valid indices and set them in A to be ones as well
A(neigh_idx(neigh_idx>=1 & neigh_idx<=numel(A))) = 1
```

---

Or use [`imdilate`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) from `Image Processing Toolbox` with a vector kernel of `ones` of length `3` -

```
A = imdilate(A,[1;1;1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it convolving with `[1 1 1]`, and setting to `1` all values greater than `0`. This works for column or row vactors.

```
x = [0;0;1;0;0];
y = double(conv(x, [1 1 1],'same')>0)
```

Comment: Oh, C**p. You just beat me... I will delete my answer as you posted it before me.... +1

Comment: @kkuilla Sorry about that. You would also need the additional thresholding step

Comment: @kkuilla - Yeah with these guys you have to really think outside the box or beat them to the answer because they're very fast. They stole all of the good answers lol.

Answer (score 0):

Purely by logical indexing:

```
>> A = [0 1 1 0 0];
>> A([A(2:end) 0] == 1 | [0 A(1:end-1)] == 1) = 1;
>> disp(A);

A =

     1     1     1     1     0
```

This probably merits an explanation.  The fact that it's a 3 element local neighbourhood makes this easy.  Essentially, take two portions of the input array:

- Portion #1: `A` starting from the second element to the last element
- Portion #2: `A` starting from the first element to the second-last element

We place the first portion into a new array and add `0` at the end of this array, and check to see which locations are equal to 1 in this new array.  This essentially shifts the array `A` over to the left by 1.  Whichever locations in this first portion are equal to 1, we set the corresponding locations in `A` to be 1.  The same thing for the second portion where we are effectively shifting the array `A` over to the right by 1.  To shift to the right by 1, we prepend a `0` at the beginning, then extract out the second portion of the array.  Whichever locations in this second portion are equal to 1 are also set to 1.

At the end of this operation, you would essentially shift `A` to the left by 1 and save this as a separate array.  Also, you would shift to the right by 1 and save this as another array.  With these two, you simply overlap on top of the original to obtain the final result.

The benefit of this method over its predecessors in this post is that this doesn't require computations of any kind (`bsxfun, conv, imdilate` etc.) and purely relies on indexing into arrays and using `logical` operators<sup>1</sup>.  This also handles boundary conditions and can work on either row or column vectors.

## Some more examples with boundary cases

```
>> A = [0 0 1 1 0];
>> A([A(2:end) 0] == 1 | [0 A(1:end-1)] == 1) = 1


A =

     0     1     1     1     1

>> A = [0 0 0 0 1];
>> A([A(2:end) 0] == 1 | [0 A(1:end-1)] == 1) = 1

A =

     0     0     0     1     1

>> A = [1 0 1 0 1];
>> A([A(2:end) 0] == 1 | [0 A(1:end-1)] == 1) = 1


A =

     1     1     1     1     1
```

---

<sup>1: This post is dedicated to [Troy Haskin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121310/troyhaskin), one who believes that almost any question (including this one) can be answered by logical indexing.</sup>